# How to use angular.copy()

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to know, wether the angular.copy() will hold the values that user entered even if the application is closed and opened. If so how do I apply it in my code.

HTML:

```
<ion-content ng-init=onViewloaded()>    
    From:
    <input type="date" ng-model="fromDate">
    To:
    <input type="date" ng-model="toDate">
    <button type="submit" ng-click="Save()">Submit</button><br>
    Data:
    {{receivedData.name}}
    {{receivedData.information}}
   </ion-content>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.receivedData;

    $scope.onViewloaded=function()
   {
     bulkDateService.getData($scope.RetrievedData);
   }
   $scope.RetrievedData = function(data,error)
  {
    $scope.receivedData=data;
  }
    $scope.save=function()
   {
    var dataToSend={'from':$scope.fromDate, 'to':$scope.toDate};
    bulkDateService.postData(dataToSend,error);
   }
```

Here,On clicking the submit button I'm able to retrieve the information based on the dates given and display the information related to it in the same page (after page reloading) but my `From date` and `TO date` fields become empty. So how do I hold the date values, so that they are retained in their respective fields even after displaying the information.

Comment: Use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

angular copy is a method, so your question does not make sense :). The question is where to store that information so that it is not lost.

What you can do is use html's localStorage / sessionStorage (ngStorage plugin can help here).

Comment: I have set my `$cookies.myCookie = 'dataToSend';` So how do I call the cookie data in the html page.

Comment: You loar it in your controller. So in controller, you set $scope.something = $cookie.myCookie.